# Xerces - Feature not recognized for SchemaFactory but OK for Validator

Tags: java, xerces, xml-validation

I am trying to set features for Xerces XML validation. I am having a hard time finding / understanding which features are valid for the `SchemaFactory` and for the `Validator`.

I have the following code:

```
SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_US_URI);
factory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", true);

Schema schema = factory.newSchema(mySchemaList);
Validator validator = schema.newValidator;
validator.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", true);
```

If I do the above I get: 
`SAXNotRecognizedException: Feature 'http://xml.org/sax/features/validation`

However if I comment out the `setFeature` for the `SchemaFactory`, setting the feature works for the `Validator`.

So questions:

1. Why can I set the feature on the `Validator` but not on the `SchemaFactory`?
2. Where can I find documentation of which features are valid for `Validator` and `SchemaFactory`?

FYI: the `SchemaFactory` I am getting is `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory`

## EDIT

Some of the other features I have tried to set with no success are:

`http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces`

`http://xml.org/sax/features/namespace-prefixes`

Answer (score 0):

From the [JavaDoc of setFeature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/SchemaFactory.html#setFeature%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29)

> Set a feature for this SchemaFactory, Schemas created by this factory,
>   and by extension, Validators and ValidatorHandlers created by those
>   Schemas.
>
> Implementors and developers should pay particular attention to how the
>   special Schema object returned by newSchema() is processed. In some
>   cases, for example, when the SchemaFactory and the class actually
>   loading the schema come from different implementations, it may not be
>   possible for SchemaFactory features to be inherited automatically.
>   Developers should make sure that features, such as secure processing,
>   are explicitly set in both places.

As you can see, some of the features might not be inherited due to some limitations. Having said that, the [Xerces 2.7.x version seems to have a bug around this which was fixed from the 2.8.x onwards](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XERCESJ-1143).

Comment: But the issue is not the the feature is not being propagated to the validator, but that it is not recognized by the factory. Also, I don't know where to look to see which features will be recognized by the factory and/or validator as I have not found any that are recognized by the factory and only one by the validator.

Comment: @JohnB xerces mailing-list is the right place for your question then